# eslint config to identify fixed pixel styles

Tags: react-native, eslint

I want to get eslint to warn me while coding when I use exact pixels as number for React styles.

For example the following code should show a linting issue:

```
StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: 138, // <= show linting issue
    margin: 8, // <= show linting issue
  }
})
```

But the following should not end up in an issue:

```
const theme = useTheme() 

StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: "100%"
    // or
    margin: theme.spacing.xl // xl === 8
  }
})
```

Comment: Take a look at the tutorial: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/extend/custom-rule-tutorial. It is pretty detailed.